# Got Forbidden through hostname but IP works

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, dns, routes, http-status-code-403

[Fobidden message through hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvxx2.png)

I built my site on aws EC2 and bought hostname through freenom(http://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en).

It had worked well before but abruptly it stopped and now just shows Forbidden message.

But when I try with IP4(http://13.125.106.155/) or public DNS, it works well.

[DNS server setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99Fp.png)

And same thing happens on other devices, too.

Where should I start to solve this problem? 
Or any idea about this situation?

Here's conf

on /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
```

on /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf:

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable Off
```

on /etc/apach2/ports.conf:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you show your httpd configuration file?

Comment: I just added them. It's on ubuntu so there're many confs. What else you need?

Comment: Isn't there an httpd.conf? If not where is the config that specifies the server name and document root?

Comment: It's on ubuntu (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215157/why-dont-i-have-a-httpd-conf-file-in-etc-apache2). And I think that the reason is 'Domain Suspension' (https://www.strategicrevenue.com/domain-suspension-registrant-information-verification-failure/)

Comment: Thanks for answering about this. I tried verification and finally got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary domain suspension is what have blocked the connection between domain and IP address exchange.

[Domain Suspension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtO4A.png)

The problem happened because of insufficient WhOIS Registrant. And also routing to suspension web page was delayed and it just had shown the 'Forbidden' page(hard to find the reason).

Finally, I got approval through verification confirmation on my email after I try resending on suspension page.

[Domain Approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEZ4a.png)